# What can make loss stop going down?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

I'm training my network on a very small dataset (size = 2) over and over again. It looks fine on the beginning but after `Epoch 34` the loss stop going down.

I though it could be caused by the `Dying Relu` problem, so I replaced all my relu activations with `Softplus`. However, the problem is still the same.

I also tried to add some Linear hidden layers combined with Softplus with no results.

If i try with a dataset with only one example, then loss goes to 0 as expected.

What can cause this behavior and how to avoid it?

```
Epoch 0
Expected: [243.0, 0.0]; Predicted: [-2367.9, 3.8]; Loss: 6059457.6000
Expected: [178.0, 32.0]; Predicted: [-1731.4, 10.9]; Loss: 3241238.0000

Epoch 1
Expected: [243.0, 0.0]; Predicted: [-1237.8, 8.1]; Loss: 1949257.6000
Expected: [178.0, 32.0]; Predicted: [-883.9, 14.1]; Loss: 1002567.6000

Epoch 2
Expected: [243.0, 0.0]; Predicted: [-602.2, 10.6]; Loss: 635017.6000
Expected: [178.0, 32.0]; Predicted: [-407.1, 15.9]; Loss: 304548.4500

...

Epoch 12
Expected: [243.0, 0.0]; Predicted: [212.6, 13.7]; Loss: 991.0653
Expected: [178.0, 32.0]; Predicted: [203.9, 18.3]; Loss: 764.2527

Epoch 13
Expected: [243.0, 0.0]; Predicted: [213.7, 13.7]; Loss: 930.9330
Expected: [178.0, 32.0]; Predicted: [204.8, 18.3]; Loss: 803.9944

...

Epoch 32
Expected: [243.0, 0.0]; Predicted: [215.1, 13.7]; Loss: 856.9812
Expected: [178.0, 32.0]; Predicted: [205.9, 18.3]; Loss: 856.9783

Epoch 33
Expected: [243.0, 0.0]; Predicted: [215.1, 13.7]; Loss: 856.9806
Expected: [178.0, 32.0]; Predicted: [205.9, 18.3]; Loss: 856.9789

Epoch 34
Expected: [243.0, 0.0]; Predicted: [215.1, 13.7]; Loss: 856.9800
Expected: [178.0, 32.0]; Predicted: [205.9, 18.3]; Loss: 856.9795

Epoch 35
Expected: [243.0, 0.0]; Predicted: [215.1, 13.7]; Loss: 856.9800
Expected: [178.0, 32.0]; Predicted: [205.9, 18.3]; Loss: 856.9795

Epoch 36
Expected: [243.0, 0.0]; Predicted: [215.1, 13.7]; Loss: 856.9800
Expected: [178.0, 32.0]; Predicted: [205.9, 18.3]; Loss: 856.9795

Epoch 37
Expected: [243.0, 0.0]; Predicted: [215.1, 13.7]; Loss: 856.9800
Expected: [178.0, 32.0]; Predicted: [205.9, 18.3]; Loss: 856.9795

Epoch 38
Expected: [243.0, 0.0]; Predicted: [215.1, 13.7]; Loss: 856.9800
Expected: [178.0, 32.0]; Predicted: [205.9, 18.3]; Loss: 856.9795

Epoch 39
Expected: [243.0, 0.0]; Predicted: [215.1, 13.7]; Loss: 856.9800
Expected: [178.0, 32.0]; Predicted: [205.9, 18.3]; Loss: 856.9795

Epoch 40
Expected: [243.0, 0.0]; Predicted: [215.1, 13.7]; Loss: 856.9800
Expected: [178.0, 32.0]; Predicted: [205.9, 18.3]; Loss: 856.9795

Epoch 41
Expected: [243.0, 0.0]; Predicted: [215.1, 13.7]; Loss: 856.9800
Expected: [178.0, 32.0]; Predicted: [205.9, 18.3]; Loss: 856.9795

Epoch 42
Expected: [243.0, 0.0]; Predicted: [215.1, 13.7]; Loss: 856.9800
Expected: [178.0, 32.0]; Predicted: [205.9, 18.3]; Loss: 856.9795
```

Here's the code:

```
class NN(Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, *_, hidden_size=200, text_max_len=200, rnn_num_layers=1, dropout=0.2):
        super(NN, self).__init__()

        self.rnn_layer_range = list(range(rnn_num_layers))
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.text_max_len = text_max_len
        self.softplus = Softplus()

        # text:
        self.text_embed = Embedding(vocab_size, hidden_size, padding_idx=0)
        self.text_conv1 = Conv2d( 1,  6, 5)
        self.text_conv2 = Conv2d( 6, 12, 5)
        self.text_conv3 = Conv2d(12, 24, 5)

        self.text_lin1  = Linear(4536, hidden_size)

        # image:
        self.img_conv1 = Conv2d( 3,  6, 5)
        self.img_conv2 = Conv2d( 6, 16, 5)
        self.img_conv3 = Conv2d(16, 20, 5)

        self.img_lin1 = Linear(2420, hidden_size)

        # union:
        self.u_size = 3*hidden_size
        self.u_linear_augment = Linear(9, hidden_size)
        self.u_gru = GRU(input_size=self.u_size, hidden_size=self.u_size, dropout=dropout)
        self.u_linear_reduce1 = Linear(self.u_size, self.u_size // 2)
        self.u_linear_reduce2 = Linear(self.u_size // 2, 2)

    def initHidden(self):
        return Variable(zeros(1, 1, self.hidden_size)), Variable(zeros(1, 1, self.u_size))

    def forward(self, text, img, data, *_, text_hidden=None, u_hidden=None):
        text_hidden, u_hidden = self.initHidden()

        # encode text
        max_len = self.text_max_len
        if len(text) < max_len:
            text = cat((text, Variable(LongTensor(max_len - len(text)).zero_())))
        text = self.text_embed(text)
        text = text.view(1, 1, max_len, self.hidden_size)
        text = max_pool2d(self.softplus(self.text_conv1(text)), 2)
        text = max_pool2d(self.softplus(self.text_conv2(text)), 2)
        text = max_pool2d(self.softplus(self.text_conv3(text)), 2)

        text = text.view(1, -1)
        text = self.softplus(self.text_lin1(text))
        text = text.view(-1, 1)


        # encode image
        img = max_pool2d(self.softplus(self.img_conv1(img)), 2)
        img = max_pool2d(self.softplus(self.img_conv2(img)), 2)
        img = max_pool2d(self.softplus(self.img_conv3(img)), 2)

        img = img.view(1, -1)
        img = self.softplus(self.img_lin1(img))
        img = img.view(-1, 1)

        # join
        data = self.softplus(self.u_linear_augment(data))
        vector = text.view(1, 1, -1)
        vector = cat((data, text, img)).view(1, 1, -1)
        for _ in self.rnn_layer_range:
            vector, u_hidden = self.u_gru(vector, u_hidden)
        vector = self.softplus(self.u_linear_reduce1(vector))
        vector = self.u_linear_reduce2(vector)
        return vector.view(-1, 1)
```

and

```
def train(neuron_network, optimizer, criterion, text, img, data, target, *_, loop_size=5):
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    loss = 0
    for _ in range(loop_size):
        output = neuron_network(text, img, data)
        loss += criterion(output, target)

    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    return loss.data[0]/loop_size
```

And here is how i'm training it:

```
neural = NN(vocab_size=len(letter_dict)+1, dropout=0, rnn_num_layers=1, hidden_size=100)
optimizer = optim.SGD(neural.parameters(), lr=0.01)
criterion = nn.MSELoss()

for epoch in range(500):
    for item in dataset:
        loss = train(neural, optimizer, criterion, item["text"], item["img"], item["data"], item["target"])
```

Comment: well the reason is most probably error in code, but since no code is provided it is hard to help

Comment: sorry. I just add the code, @lejlot

Comment: Try turning all regularization off (weight decay and dropout) and check if you see the same behavior

Comment: @dgumo, I turned them all off and the behavior persists.

Now It get stucked at epoch 46

Comment: I'm not sure there's a bug here, actually. From just skimming your code, it looks like you do some text-convolution. Depending on the length of your text, that means that you may never actually get a loss of 0. And you initial loss is between 3000 and 6000 _times_ larger than your final loss. Your model might actually have converged.